# ZIP Directory AES encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, zip

Is is possible to encrypt a zip file with a directory in it but not files? or if this is not possible, how about encrypting the directory itself?

I have a directory with subdirectories. And i need to encrypt it. I read a suggestion to zip it first then encrypt the zipfile.

I also don't want a zip of encrypted files. just in case someone would suggest it. I really need the directory or the zip file of it to be encrypted. or is this the only way possible?

and how do i know my files have been encrypted?

My program is written in java. and being applied in android.

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: I don't think zip files can contain empty directories. And what's an encrypted directory supposed to be? Do you want the filenames of contained files to be encrypted?

Comment: it's not empty. it actually has files with different file extensions.. I was hoping to encrypt the files and if possible the whole directory. in general, i need the whole thing encrypted..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the ZIP specification allows for the content of each of the files to be encrypted, and, in theory, with a separate password per file.

If you want to encrypt a directory and all the files below it, then you need to archive the directory and encrypt the archive. A directory is not considered an encryptable item, as it's only a place-holder - all the information related to the directory is part of the zip entry attributes, and not encryptable, as only the content of the file are encrypted (this is per the zip spec).

To determine if the file has been encrypted, you can try extracting using a zip tool without specifying a password. The program should prompt for a password for the encrypted file. **Note** as of this writing, none of info-zip tools support AES encryption, so you will probably not be able to test extract the files using this method.

With zipinfo look at the 'status' column, and if it's all in capitals then it's encrypted (good rule of thumb):

```
host:~/bin% zip hello.zip radio    
updating: radio (deflated 30%)
host:~/bin% zipinfo hello.zip
Archive:  hello.zip   307 bytes   1 file
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx      211 tx defN  9-Jun-09 11:33 radio
1 file, 211 bytes uncompressed, 147 bytes compressed:  30.3%
```

Note the lower case `tx` for the non password protected entry

```
host:~/bin% zip -P fred hello.zip radio
  adding: radio (deflated 30%)
host:~/bin% zipinfo hello.zip
Archive:  hello.zip   335 bytes   1 file
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx      211 TX defN  9-Jun-09 11:33 radio
1 file, 211 bytes uncompressed, 147 bytes compressed:  30.3%
```

Note the upper case `TX` for the password protected entry.

The jar tool produces the awesome message (ymmv):

```
host:~/bin% zip -P fred hello.zip radio
updating: radio (deflated 30%)
host:~/bin% jar tvf hello.zip          
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (encrypted entry)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:115)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1004)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

Comment: will encrypting the zip file affect the organization of the files inside? especially when it has many subfolders?

Comment: Encrypting a zip entry does not affect the organization of the zip file, all that happens is the compressed content is replaced by encrypted compressed content. If you're talking zip-within-zip, then you're going to have to handle that somehow. If you're using [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/), then, I think you can only unzip to another file, so traces of the decrypted content will be on the android file system